# How to use a variable to define bsub jobname?

Tags: bash, jobs, lsf

I do not know the maximum number of jobs a priori. So when I keep it a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
caselist=/my/caselist.txt
N=`cat $caselist | wc -l`

#BSUB -J myjob[1-$N]
...
...
```

(I call the above script `myjob.lsf`)

And submit the job as `bsub < myjob.lsf`, I get:

> Bad job name. Job not submitted.

So is there a way I can use a variable in `#BSUB -J myjob[1-$N]` within `myjob.lsf`?

Comment: What's the relationship between `caselist.txt` and `myjob.lsf`?

Comment: The above script is named `myjob.lsf`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: The code in the job will not be executed when you schedule it. I'm wondering if this isn't an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) about how to submit a sequence of jobs related to the information in the text file.

Comment: For your comparison, `#BSUB -J myjob[1-10]` executes fine by `bsub < myjob.lsf`.

Comment: You are right @tripleee. I figured the workaround but generating the `N` is more manageable if can be done inside the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside the file does not get evaluated when you pass it to `bsub`. You can probably remove it from the script entirely, and instead submit it differently.

```
bsub -J "myjob[1-$(wc -l </my/caselist.txt)]" <myjob.lsf
```

(speculating a bit about the `bsub` options; the manuals I could find online were rather bad).